# Tailwind arbitrary values does not accept variables

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

In tailwind why does `bg-[#5ad0a1]` work, however assigning the hex to variable for example `const color = '#5ad0a1';` then `bg-[${color}]` not work?

```
<span className={`inline-flex items-center rounded-md bg-[${color}] px-2 py-2 text-md font-base text-[${color}]`}>
 {params?.value}
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Tailwind needs the actual color (#5ad0a1) to be able to parse the code to create the css. It does not convert it to html with javascript and then parse the code. So it never sees `#5ad0a1` only ever `${color}`

So it is likely creating something like

```
.bg-[${color}] {
  background-color: ${color};
}
```

What you can try is use css variables

In your css add, or if you need it to be variables add the root css in your js.

```
:root {
  --main-color: #5ad0a1;
}
```

Then in your class use

```
bg-[var(--main-color)]
```

Answer (score 0):

From tailwind's [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#classes-aren-t-generated):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is
> that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings
> in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names
> together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate
> the corresponding CSS:

So this is wrong and tailwind wont find the classes:

```js
<span className={`bg-[${color}] text-[${color}]`}>
      {children}
</span>
```

The recommended way is to map your props to static class names:

```js
const colorVariants = {
  bg: "bg-[#5ad0a1]",
  text: "text-[#5ad0a1]"
};

return (
  <span
    className={`inline-flex items-center rounded-md ${colorVariants.bg} px-2 py-2 text-md font-base ${colorVariants.text}`}
  >
    Hii
  </span>
);
```